# Measuring the motorable distance between two points by open Source technology

Tags: qgis, network-analyst, route, shortest-path, big-data

**I'm trying to generate a solution to get the Shortest motorable distance between two points by open source GIS technology ?**
Our Input layer: Road layer for the AOI (Include flow direction and obstruction ) &
Start & End Point location info.
I'm looking for suggestions & direction to build this solutions.

Note: ARCGIS Network Analysis tool & Shortest route between two points in QGIS. I already tried out, but its not scalable for big data.
Followed Resources: https://gis-ops.com/open-source-routing-engines-and-algorithms-an-overview/#user-content-pgrouting

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.